# use project.json with xamarin.android

Tags: android, project.json

I try to use the new project.json file format with a Xamarin Android project. I made all in the same way I did for the PCL's I have in this project, except for the frameworks of course:

```
{
    "dependencies": {

    },
    "frameworks": {
        "MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0": {}
    },
    "supports": {}
}
```

But when I try to add new nuget packages VS creates a new packages.config and ignores the project.json.

Is project.json not supported for something other than uwp, pcl's and asp.net core even with the latest VS2015?

Answer (score 0):

I use this project.json in my project:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win": {}
  }
}
```

It took several tries until it worked properly. Foremost I had to add a nuget package normaly first, delete the package.config and remove every reference in the csproj. I recommend that you search for "nuget" in the csproj and remove all lines with it.